# send fewer parameters to stored procedure generated by EF code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

my Application is using EF 6 code first

i have a model with some non required properties, i used modelbuilder to generate stored procedures, the problem is i dont want to send the non required fields to the database during insert or update as most of them are with default constraints

i tried to edit the definition of the stored procedures in sqlserver but i can't seem to sync it with EF, it says "too many parameters specified " ,

i tried to generate migrations and then edited the definition of the stored procedure but when i update-database it say object already Exists.

is there a way to send arbitary number of parameters to database and

is there a way to sync edited stored procedures to EF

every suggestion will be highly appreciated

Edit : 
model

```
 public class BattalionDetails
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public short ID { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(300)]
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Battallion Name")]
        public string BattalionName { get; set; }


        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Battallion NO")]
        public string BattalionNO { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Number Of Person In Batallion")]
        public short NumberOfCadetsInBatallion { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Description (if any)")]

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string  Description { get; set; }

        public bool IsSynced { get; set; } = false;
        public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

here is the Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BattalionDetails_Insert]
    @BattalionName [nvarchar](300),
    @BattalionNO [nvarchar](50),
    @NumberOfCadetsInBatallion [smallint],
    @Description [nvarchar](max)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT [dbo].[BattalionDetails]([BattalionName], [BattalionNO], [NumberOfCadetsInBatallion], [Description])
    VALUES (@BattalionName, @BattalionNO, @NumberOfCadetsInBatallion, @Description)

    DECLARE @ID smallint
    SELECT @ID = [ID]
    FROM [dbo].[BattalionDetails]
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()

    SELECT t0.[ID]
    FROM [dbo].[BattalionDetails] AS t0
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[ID] = @ID
END
```

here is the controller part :

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BattalionName,BattalionNO,NumberOfCadetsInBatallion,Description")] BattalionDetails battalionDetails)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.BattalionDetails.Add(battalionDetails);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(battalionDetails);
        }
```

Edit 2 :

here is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BattalionDetails](
    [ID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BattalionName] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [BattalionNO] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [NumberOfCadetsInBatallion] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsSynced] [bit] NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.BattalionDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

the exception i get is

**Procedure or function BattalionDetails_Insert has too many arguments specified**

Comment: you should share you SP & model code

Comment: @Patel i updated the question

Comment: you haven't set default values for stored procedure parameters

Comment: @AksheyBhat check it , i added table details

Comment: Are you sending value for ID column too?

Comment: @AksheyBhat no , i am not sending the ID , its auto incremented PK and IDENTITY (1,1)

Comment: ok I saw it in your code. Now you have edited. is it working now?

Comment: @AksheyBhat you can check the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

try setting default values in your stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BattalionDetails_Insert]
    @BattalionName [nvarchar](300) = null,
    @BattalionNO [nvarchar](50) = null,
    @NumberOfCadetsInBatallion [smallint] = 0,
    @Description [nvarchar](max)
AS
```

The above code sets default values for 3 parameters now those parameters should be optional in your code.

Comment: these fields are required , please have a look at table creation code i set the default values there , hence if i dont provide them the defaults will be set

Comment: i have given just an example. if you want the values from Default Constraints set in SQL then just set the default parameter value to NULL in stored procedure. This way when you won't pass the value of such variable from your code, it will take the value set by default contraint

Comment: but the thing is i dont want to send the values to the database without a need , i mean for the sake of effieincy , otherwise default scaffolding code is working fine